# Incorrect trigonometric ratios in Stewart Calculus 7th Ed textbook?

Tags: trigonometry

In the 7th Edition of Stewart Calculus, I see the below table of trigonometric ratios for common angles:

[image]

Additionally, the exercises related to this section state that the $\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$ are $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$, respectively.

Every other resource I find on this has this as $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ rather than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Am I missing something?  Is there any situation under which $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is correct?

Comment: $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)=1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: I think you mean $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ which anyway is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Corrected it to $\sqrt(2)/2$ in original post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\cos\frac{\pi}{4} = \sin \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
It is because
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$

Comment: Ah, so it's the rationalized version of $\sqrt(2)/2$, of course.  Thanks for the insight.